# OpenGL - rendering to 3D Texture has no effect on texture

Tags: c++, opengl, shader

I am trying to splat vertex information into a 3D Texture.

Corresponding C++ code:

```
GLuint color_tex;
GLuint fb;
glGenTextures(1, &color_tex);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, color_tex);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_REPEAT);
glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL_R32UI, 32, 32, 32, 0, GL_RED_INTEGER, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL);
  //-------------------------
glGenFramebuffers(1, &fb);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fb);
 //Attach one of the faces of the Cubemap texture to this FBO
glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, color_tex, 0);
//-------------------------
//Does the GPU support current FBO configuration?
GLenum status;
status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
switch(status)
{
    case GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE:
        std::cout << "good" << std::endl;
    default:
        break;
}
//-------------------------
glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glUseProgram(splat_vertex_ids);
glBindVertexArray( mVAO );
glDrawArrays(mPrimitiveType, 0, mDrawSize);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

GLuint content[32*32*32];
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, color_tex);
glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL_RED_INTEGER, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, &content);

for(int i = 0; i< 32*32*32; ++i)
    if(content[i] != 0)
        std::cout << content[i] << std::endl;
```

I read back the content to check if anything was rendered, but the texture only contains 0's.

My first thought was, that my shaders don't work correctly, so I replaced them by this :

Geometry Shader:

```
#version 330
layout(points) in;
layout(points, max_vertices = 1) out;

in vec3[] vPosition;

out vec2 oTexCoord;

void main(void)
{
    oTexCoord = vec2(0.2);

    gl_Position = vec4(0.2,0.2, 0.2,1);
    gl_Layer = 0;
    EmitVertex();
    EndPrimitive();
}
```

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 330

layout(location = 0)in vec3 aPosition;

uniform vec3 uChunkStart;
uniform float uRes;

out vec3 vPosition;

void main(void)
{
    vPosition = aPosition;
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 330

in vec2 oTexCoord;

out uint color;

void main(void)
{
    color = 1337u;
}
```

Don't know whats wrong with this. Shouldn't it create a single dot? My first time doing such a thing.

**EDIT:** Rendering to a 2D texture also fails

Comment: Can I still use gl_Layer in my shader program when using `glFramebufferTextureLayer` or am I restricted to the bound layer?

Comment: I think I misunderstood what you were trying to do by outputting to `gl_Layer` **0**. In your 3D texture, a point with Z=0.2 in NDC-space would really correspond to mipmap level 0, layer 18. --- 31*(0.2+1.0)/2.0

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman the shaders are only placeholders. Later on the input will be a point set with vec3 coords and there ID should be splat into the texture according to there coordinate. I only use this shaders at the moment for testing. I will need to render to all layers at once.

Comment: Not sure if this is causing your immediate problem, but your texture is not texture complete. `GL_LINEAR` is not a valid filter mode for integer textures. You need to use `GL_NEAREST` for `MIN_FILTER` and `MAG_FILTER`.

Comment: @RetoKoradi changed that and run 2 queries anlong. 1024 primitives are generated but 0 samples pass